# preg_replace on customize short-code

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have the following code:

```
{bookielink href="bet-at-home"} body content{/bookielink}
```

and I want to get the following:

```
<a href="index.php?bookie=bet-at-home">body content</a>
```

This is my tries:

```
$buffer = preg_replace("/.*{bookielink[^>]*}|.*/si", "<a>", $buffer);
$buffer = preg_replace("/.*{\/bookielink}|.*/si", "</a>", $buffer);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php)

Comment: @ajreal: not at all. Kicsi is trying to _generate_ HTML from a custom format.

Comment: Sorry, and the down vote removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following:

```
$buffer = 'foo {bookielink href="bet-at-home"} body content{/bookielink} bar';
echo preg_replace(
    '#{bookielink\s+href="([^"]*)"\s*}([^{]+){/bookielink}#i', 
    '<a href="index.php?bookie=$1">$2</a>', 
    $buffer
);
```

will print:

```
foo <a href="index.php?bookie=bet-at-home"> body content</a> bar
```

Comment: The regex seems fairly straightforward to me, but if you need some explanation, just say so, and I'll expand a bit.